# Way to input entire 2D array at once in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I wrote this code for a 1D array:

```
int[] arr= new int[9];
arr=Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), int.Parse)
```

It takes my whole input at once and converts it as an array besides removing spaces. Where input is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`.

This same concept was tried for 2D arrays but still can't match. Here is my code,

```
int[,] arr = new int[3, 3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        arr[i, j] =Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), int.Parse);
    }
}
```

My input is:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

What is the solution? How can I input the entire 2D array at once in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `Console.ReadLine` for every line and then put in the values:

```cs
int[,] arr = new int[3, 3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    int[] temp = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), int.Parse);

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        arr[i, j] = temp[j];
    }
}
```